# What queries can I use to select data?

Tags: python, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, postgresql, postgis-2.0

Which queries can I use to select the following information:
How many towns are within a distance of 3km of both a road and a railway and are within 6km of the coast?
And any towns that have both a railway and a road within 2km of them, i have shape file of road , railway and towns.

Comment: You've got a lot of tags here which don't seem to relate to your question.  Why have you added "python", "postgresql" and "postgis-2.0"?  Do you require a pythonic solution?  You mention your data is in shapefiles?  Why the postgresqld and postgis tags?

Answer (score 5):

In ArcGIS you don't need to create a buffer layer as AllenT suggested.  You can do it just by using the selection tools without creating any additional layers.

Firstly, you will need a layer representing your coastline.  Depending on where your area of interest is, you may need to either digitise it or download it.

Then, you can use [Select by Location](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s50000002q000000) to do the following:

1. Select from Towns which are within a distance of 3km of Railroads.
   [image]
2. Select from the previous selection (note, you will need to change the selection method here) from Towns which are a distance of 3km of Roads.

   [image]
3. Select from the previous selection from Towns which are a distance of 6km of the Coastline.
   [image]

The result will be a selection of towns which are 3km of a road and railway and 6km of the coastline.

You can run your second query in much the same way.  Essentially, it's the same as the first two steps above.

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to buffer your different layers to the distance you are interested in (coast 6km, road to 3km, etc).  Next you will intersect those buffers.  Finally, you can do a select by location query:  chose 'intersect' or 'contains' (whichever fits your needs); using your cities and your intersected buffers.
From there you can export the data into a new layer, or whatever else you want to do with them.